# Media queries don't do anything

Tags: html, css, sass, gulp-sass

I've been doing HTML and CSS with SASS for a while and all my responsive was working until today, suddenly my css media queries stopped reacting.

They are in the css file that is being loaded on the web page, but no elements react to them ... I can't copy a full css file of 3k lines to here..

But I think I'm missing something basic. I'm using gulp-sass and it reports no errors when processing the css.

I'm going nuts over this and I can't figure out the problem. Everything was working until today and I need to deliver a project till monday and I can't do the responsive.

All the queries were working. I didn't change anything today , when I ran the project the queries wouldn't do anything .

Any suggestions on what it may be ? Thanks guys.

Comment: A whole bunch of possibilities. Solar flares, aliens from Mars, little people inside your computer short-circuiting your motherboard... :) On a more serious note, did you restart your computer since yesterday? If you are using source control (which I hope you are if your file is 3k lines long) you could try updating to previous changesets and figure out where things went awry. It is entirely possible that your CSS wasn't working yesterday and you couldn't tell.

Comment: followed your suggestion, got the version from yesterday, runned , working. compiled the sass stopped working, i didn't change anything. maybe the error is on gulp-sass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tests are usually your best bet. Make sure your media queries are at the bottom most of your prioritized CSS file - to ensure they aren't being overwritten. Regardless how many thousand lines your code is:

1) Comment out all your media queries
2) Run a test, for example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
      background-color: black;
    }
  }
```

3) Resize your browser to a width smaller than 600px, if your background colour changes to black, chances are nothing is wrong with your preprocessors and its time to debug your code.

4) Comment out your media queries one code block at a time until you discover the block that doesn't work.

5) Fix it. Relief

Comment: All my responsive imports are after all the desktop imports , already tried to comment it, gonna do a single one and comment all others and see if it works. If it works I'm gonna comment 1 import at a time ..

Comment: nope, found nothing. reinstalled gulp-sass and it's working now. meh , thanks anyways for the suggestion.